# Subgroups Lattice of Automorphism Group of Linear Groups

Tags: group-theory

Could someone tell me the subgroups lattice of $PSL(n,p^k)$ or could someone tell me sources I should read to know all about $Aut(PSL(n,p^k))$ and its subgroups lattice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I write this answer to just leave this question from list of unanswered questions. 
 Thomas Connor and Dimitri Leemans has published an online **[Atlas of Subgroup Lattices of Finite Almost Simple Groups](http://student.ulb.ac.be/~tconnor/atlaslat/)**.

> This atlas contains all subgroup lattices of almost simple groups G such that S≤G≤Aut(S) and S is a simple group of order less than 1 million appearing in the Atlas of Finite Groups by Conway et al. Some simple groups and almost simple groups or order larger than 1 million have also been included, but not in a systematic way.

Comment: The Atlas of Connor and Leemans has now disappeared. Do you know if it has migrated somewhere or if it's lost?